# Calculate height of a probability distribution

Tags: probability

I found an equation for calculating the probability of the mean from a 2D covariance matrix in a math library I've been using and trying to understand why it's valid. The equation is $$\text{probAtMean} = \frac{1}{ 2 \pi \sqrt{\text{determinant of covariance}}}$$

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ where $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. The corresponding pdf of this multivariate normal with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is given by

$f_{Y}(X)=(\frac{1}{2\pi})^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{|\Sigma|^{\frac{1}{2}}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(X-\mu)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(X-\mu)}$.

. Then evaluating $f_{Y}(\mu)=(\frac{1}{2\pi})^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{|\Sigma|^{\frac{1}{2}}}$.

See here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function